# VS2010 SP1 Installation. “The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable”

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Ultimately, I'm trying to install the windows phone app SDK so that I can put an app I've made on my phone.

To do this, I am told I need to install SP1.

When I attempt this I get the following:

> "The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable visual studio riaservices.msi"

I download the riaservices.msi and point the dialog to it, and I get the message:

> "The file is not a valid installation package for the product WCF RIA Services V1.0 for VS 2010."

I've downloaded the ISO as mentioned in a related post on this website, but I've no idea what I'm doing with that now it's mounted.

Some of the features I've tried to install have asked me to insert the CD which I don't have, I downloaded it for free from a university scheme.

Can anyone help me fix this? It's infuriating beyond belief.

Comment: I saw this recently. I don't remember the exact details, but I think uninstalling VS2010 SP1,rebooting, then trying the installation again worked for me.

Comment: I've not installed SP1 yet to uninstall it!

Comment: That's my point! I needed to uninstall the SP even though it didn't install successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone answered the question over on SuperUser, this got a fair few views so here's a link to there:

https://superuser.com/questions/460773/vs2010-sp1-installation-the-feature-you-are-trying-to-use-is-on-a-network-reso

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of error found while uninstalling programs, I saw this error when I try to uninstall Java. But it is common i-tones, Blackberry software and certain other applications also.

As a Technical Support I met this problem and found a solution for a client PC running with Windows XP.
All the step by step procedure I written here

[[Solved] The Feature That You Are Trying to Use is On a Network Resource That is Unavailable Java](http://www.smartpctricks.com/2013/09/solved-the-feature-that-you-are-trying-to-use-is-on-a-network-resource-that-is-unavailable-java.html)